Excessive Space Between Ionic Angular Child Components
I'm working on an Ionic Angular project, and I'm running into an issue where there's a lot of space between two child components within a parent component. Here's what my code looks like:
For my first child component, I have an ion-header with several buttons:
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <div class="header-controls">
      <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button class="button-spacer">
          <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button class="button-spacer">
          <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button class="button-spacer">
          <ion-icon name="chatbubble"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


CSS:
.header-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-spacer {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

For the other child component, it's just a simple header tag with no CSS:
<h4>Title</h4>

In the parent component, I'm embedding these children like this:
<app-home-page-header></app-home-page-header>
<app-activities-title></app-activities-title>

but when displayed; the first and 2nd component has a lot of vertical space between each other i.e pushing title to the end.
Display
I tried setting
margin-bottom: 50%;

and it works but I don't want it this way.

is the repo public, share the github link if it is

unfortunately no, its just a sample project

Your Activities component is actually a content, while Home is a header with tabs - so try wrapping the Activities component's html content in ion-content tag. Home's Ion-header will reserve the viewport for the tabs, while your non-ion-content (Activities component) will be displayed 'from the bottom', unless it's in ion-content.
